# How do I use data from mysql database as a variable list

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use the results of a mysql query as the values for a variable in a loop. However, the results from the query are returned as a tuple with the value indicating a long integer. Here's the example result:
((2136L,),(41L,),(340L,),...etc)

For some reason, when I try to use the results, the value literally contains the "L," suffix, and so I can't use it at all. Because it is a tuple, I can't change it to an integer and drop the suffix.

Here's the basic version of my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","testdb")
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = ("SELECT thisid FROM thislist")
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

mynumber = str(data[0]) #here i get (2136L,) instead of '2136'

mystring = 'The last thing should be a number as a string: ' + mynumber
```

The end result is "The last thing should be a number as a string: 2136L,", when what I need is "...as a string: 2136".

I'm a python noob, but I've just been having the hardest time finding a solution to what I imagine is a pretty simple problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a tuple of tuples; in other words, it returns a tuple of rows, each of which is itself a tuple of columns. That means that `data[0]` in your code is still a tuple.

You could fix this by accessing `data[0][0]`, but in your case, since you only want to fetch one row, you could use `fetchone()` and still access `data[0]`.

Comment: If, like me, you find comma less ugly than brackets, you can do `data, = fecthone()`

Comment: Wow - thanks for the quick responses! To be clear, the example code was just a single reference, but this is actually for a loop against all records. I think fetchall() is the way I need to go.

Comment: Fair enough. The point is that each entry is still a tuple, even if it contains only one value.

Comment: I played some more, and what I actually ended up doing is this:
    mynumber = str(data[1])[1:-3]
seemed to do the trick for me. If there's a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just re-read your answer, and it makes more sense now. I can still use data[0][0], so long as I account for that in the way the loop runs. Perfect!